# How can I translate SQL query to to django ORM

Tags: python, sql, django

I'm working on making some data consults in Django but I don't understand quite well its ORM system yet. I need to get the transactions' quantity for a particularly transaction's projections. To put it briefly, I want to translate this SQL query to Python/Django syntax:

```
select cp.name, count(*) as total
from core_transaction ct 
inner join core_projection cp 
on ct.projection_id = cp.id
group by cp.name
```

These are the models involved:

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    projection = models.ForeignKey('Projection', blank=False, null=False, related_name='transactions')

class Projection(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: You can't. For example `.filter() .exclude Q object` has the same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do this with an [**`.annotate(…)`** clause [Django-doc]]:

```
from django.db.models import Count

Projection.objects.annotate(
    total=Count('transactions')
)
```

The `Projection` objects that arise from this queryset will have an extra attribute `.total` that contain the number of `Transaction`s.